# How to ensure submake don't get flags of make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I don't want to propagate my flags of make to submake. Through which flag can I do this?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "flags".  Giving an example is best.

Comment: Makeflag variable @MadScientist

Comment: @MadScientist can you please tell best references to learn about gnu make and also some handson?

Comment: How about the gnu make manual: [https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html]. More specifically https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html#Options_002fRecursion

Comment: I'm sorry, but "Makeflag variable" doesn't mean anything to me...?  Again, if you provided an example we could be much more useful.

Comment: Try `info make 'Options/Recursion`